# Email address in profile

Tags: support, profile-page

How do I control if my email address is shown or not shown (publicly) in my [profile page](https://superuser.com/users/144147/kevin-fegan) on SU?

Comment: By the way, your real name isn't shown either. Not that it matters in your case, but you can check in a private browser window just to make sure.

Comment: @slhck - What do you mean by ***'...check in a private browser window...'***? Would this be if I logged out from SU and then viewed my Profile page?

Comment: Yeah, like visiting your profile from (anonymous) user's point of view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your email address is never shown publicly.

Only moderators and Stack Exchange staff can see what it is. It is also not shown by default and instead shows:

> email (click to show)

However, this only applies to the email field. If you enter your email address in the About Me section it will be publicly visible.